# XSD Error: attribute 'substitutiongroup' cannot appear in element 'element'

Tags: xsd

Getting `attribute 'substitutiongroup' cannot appear in element 'element'` error with this:

```
  <xs:complexType name="Attributes" abstract="false">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Attribute" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" />
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="DutyRating" substitutionGroup="Attribute"/>
      <xs:element name="Width" substitutionGroup="Attribute"/>
      <xs:element name="SampleSet" substitutionGroup="Attribute"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The attribute *substitutionGroup* can only be used if the element its a child of the *schema* tag. In addition, the way you're trying to define an attribute inside an element it's not correct (you probablly wanted to use some complexType).

Answer (score 0):

You should use this xsd...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    targetNamespace="yourNamespace" xmlns:prefix="yourNamespace">

   <xs:complexType name="Attributes" abstract="false">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Attribute" substitutionGroup="prefix:Attribute"/>
      <xs:element name="DutyRating" substitutionGroup="prefix:Attribute"/>
      <xs:element name="Width" substitutionGroup="prefix:Attribute"/>
      <xs:element name="SampleSet" substitutionGroup="prefix:Attribute"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:element name="Attribute" type="prefix:Attribute"/>
  <xs:complexType  name="Attribute" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" />
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

I hope I've given you all the answers about your question.

Comment: That xsd is not valid. As I said in my comment The attribute substitutionGroup can only be used if the element who has the attribute its a direct child of the schema tag. In addition, the attributes *nillable*, *maxOccurs* and *minOccurs* can never be part of the *complexType* element.